# Calculating Length of an Elliptical Arc

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I am trying to calculate the arclength of a section of an ellipse, given the correspoding parametrization angle $\phi$. While doing so, I am running into problems with elliptic integrals. The following paragraphs contain more details.

Suppose the ellipse parametrized by $\Gamma(\phi) = (a\cdot\cos(\phi), b\cdot\sin(\phi))$, where $a > b > 0$ and $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]$.

Now, fix a $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]$, then I want to calculate the length of the elliptical arc ranging from $0$ to $\phi$. I am aware that the exact solution involves (incomplete) elliptical integrals of the second kind, and am only looking for a numerical approximation.

I tried using the `ArcLength` function:`ArcLength[{b*Cos[l], a*Sin[l]}, {l, 0, $\phi$}]`, which returns `8 EllipticE[3/4]`. In particular, it does not evaluate the elliptical integral. However, if I cast the `3/4` to float, Mathematica does evaluate `8 EllipticE[0.75] = 9.68845`.

I now have two questions:

1. Am I correct in assuming that my overall approach should lead to a valid result?
2. Why does casting to float lead to mathematica evaluating the elliptic integral?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! 1. Yes. 2. Mathematica is primarily a _symbolic_ computational engine. For example, it will always leave $\pi$ in its symbolic form, unless you explicitly tell it to get you numerical result. You can do this with function [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html), for example: ``N[Pi]`` or ``N[ArcLength[{2*Cos[l], 3*Sin[l]}, {l, 0, Pi/4}]]``. Also read about this in tutorial about [Numerical Calculations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalCalculations.html).

Comment: Use `N[8 EllipticE[3/4]]` to get a floating-point approximation of an exact result.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
a = 10; b = 5;
ell[phi_] := {a Cos[phi], b Sin[phi]};
ParametricPlot[ell[phi], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
ArcLength[ell[phi], {phi, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Now, the arc length with exact numbers:

```
ArcLength[ell[phi], {phi, 0, Pi}]

(* 10 EllipticE[-3] *)
```

Remember, that machine numbers are not exact and that there are a finite number of machine numbers, but infinite number of exact numbers. Therefore, to express the arc length in exact numbers we can not use machine numbers. However, if we want to express the arc length approximately in machine numbers we can either give the function or the limits in machine numbers like e.g.:

```
ArcLength[ell[phi], {phi, 0., Pi}]

(* 24.2211*)
```

Or:

```
ArcLength[1. ell[phi], {phi, 0, Pi}]

(* 24.2211 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using `Region` functionality:

```
ℛ = ParametricRegion[
{a Cos[ϕ], b Sin[ϕ]}, {{ϕ, 0, ψ}}]
```

Example Plot:

```
Region[ℛ /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, ψ -> 3 π/2}]
```

[image]

Using the same values as used by Daniel Huber:

```
ArcLength[ℛ /. {a -> 10, b -> 5, ψ -> π}]
```

> 10 EllipticE[-3]

You can use `//N` to get a numeric output.